# Which is better: cURL or fopen (with a stream context)

Tags: php, curl

What differences are between `curl()` and `fopen()`(with a [stream context](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php)) while trying to get remote content.

Flexibility? Feature-rich? or What.. Is there something, that one can do, and another cant?

Comment: Personally I always use CURL, it's very powerful and there is libs for all languages.

Comment: I find curl to be more easily extensible for most tasks. The only thing more extensible than curl is `fsockopen`, but you're sending raw commands at that point. If all you need is the content downloaded, `file_get_contents`

Comment: Streams API is counter-intuitive and Curl API is simply insane. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález if you can, write a broader answer, will be good, to know what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, both the PHP curl extension and streams are dinosaurs from the PHP/4 days with the kind of API you could expect from the early days of the language: incoherent and with magic features that happen to be a security hole, such as `@` prefixes in strings that trigger file uploads (curl) and remote downloads taking place in the least expected places (such as `include` statements).

However, unlike other agey extensions like mysql or mcrypt, both of these appear to have been properly maintained along the years so I'd dare say that in 2017 they are both equality safe and reasonably feature-packed. Of course, none of them are object-oriented or nice to use and that led to creation of wrappers like [Guzzle](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) and standardisation attempts like [PSR-7](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/).

If we stick to plain HTTP, I believe the feature set is roughly the same, except that Curl has native support for `multipart/form-data` file uploads (with streams you need to implement it yourself, although it isn't difficult) and cookie handling.

Also, Curl has been heavily used along the years and you'll possibly find better documentation and less outdated information about it.

The key point of PHP streams is that they go way beyond HTTP (you can even register your own protocols) and they integrate nicely with several other PHP extensions (most builtin functions that accept file pointers will also accept streams). Curl, however, is mostly a self-contained wrapper on top of the C extension of the same name.

As about availability, I've seen both features missing from hosting plans, but that tends to happen on lame plans purchased by unaware customers.

To sum up: both are ugly, both get the job done. Benchmarks aside (I've done none) it's mostly a matter of preference... until you need a feature that one can do and the other cannot :-)

Answer (score 2):

This question has been answered multiple times before, but here is my take on it.

Curl is a lot more powerful when it comes to streaming, sending, receiving and everything else you can possibly want to do.

fopen is not designed for web-requests in general and can only do GET requests easily. POST requests are counter-intuitive and are probably more of a hack than an acceptable practice.

Curl supports SSL, custom headers, cookies, file upload and is by default available on all hosting provides, while url requests with fopen are frequently disabled and have to be re-enabled by administrator.

Additionally, unless you are using a framework which has its own implementation for web requests, you should always stick with CURL because everyone is familiar with it.

Comment: `fopen()` can do POST. However, the overall API is so counter-intuitive (you need to pass a proper stream context as 4th parameter) that many people think it cannot.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks. Modified answer.